# How to set up two-factor authentication with OTP on FreeBSD?

Tags: security, freebsd, ssh, password, pam

I have a FreeBSD hosted server that I like to be able to get to from anywhere. Normally I use SSH publickey to log in, or if I don't have my SSH private key available then I might use regular password over SSH. However, when logging in from an untrusted machine there's always the risk of a keylogger capturing my password as I type it.

FreeBSD already has [support for OPIE](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/one-time-passwords.html) which is a one-time password scheme. This works great, but the one-time password is the *only* authentication needed. If I print out a list of one-time passwords to use later, then if I lose that list then that's all somebody needs.

I'd like to set up the authentication so that I need a one-time password *plus* something I know (a password, except not my usual login password). I have a feeling the answer has something to do with [PAM](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/pam/) (and `/etc/pam.d/sshd`) but I'm not certain on the details.

How can I set up authentication where two methods are required?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to use a password that is something other than the one for your normal account, try `security/pam_pwdfile` from the ports tree.
Basically, it allows you to use an alternate file (format: `username:crypted_password`) to authenticate against.
To use it, put the following line in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` **right before** the line for `pam_opie`:

```
auth    required    /usr/local/lib/pam_pwdfile.so    pwdfile    /path/to/pwd/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Duo Security (our company) offers an [open-source package](https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_unix/) that supports OTP, phone callback, SMS, and smartphone push authentication for SSH with passwords, pubkey, or any primary auth mechanism - with or without PAM:

http://blog.duosecurity.com/2011/04/announcing-duos-two-factor-authentication-for-unix/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this uses pam, it should be as simple as putting two required modules in /etc/pam.d/. One for Opie, and one for your other auth. (say, normal UNIX password)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using pam-radius.  It should compile on BSD.  All enterprise-capable two-factor authentication systems support radius.  Radius is a very standard standard so you will gain great flexibility.

HTH.