# logging into the system using one time passwords which are sent via SMS

Tags: security, login, password, pam, sms

I have to implement an additional layer of protection in the system. The user has to log in to the system with the password he received in the text message. I don't know which module I should look for and how to configure it. Has any of you implemented a similar solution and can you tell me how to solve this task?

The solution can be implemented on any linux distribution.

Comment: Do you mean `ssh` login? Is modern 2FA also an option or does it have to be SMS?

Comment: And: do you really just want to send a password via sms or do you want the users to enter their password/authenticate themselves with pubkey first?

Comment: I mean login into the local system. Yes, it has to be SMS. Users can enter their credentials first but it is not required.  I heard there's a special module in linux for this type of solution.

Comment: Authy should do that, but it's not free AFAIK. If you want to do it yourself, you'd need to be able to send sms either through a thrid party API or through your own gateway. Perhaps [LinOTP](https://www.linotp.org/) could work? There are some tips in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/how-to-set-up-two-factor-authentication-with-otp-on-freebsd) as well. Just be advised the SMS OTP is deprecated.